# Fixing brew doctor warnings/errors

Tags: ruby, rvm, homebrew

I have recently installed Homebrew and RVM. However, when I tried to install a new version of Ruby into RVM:...

> rvm install 2.2

I got the following error:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
ERROR: '/usr/local/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

So I ran the doctor command to view errors and saw:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: /usr/local/bin isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.
```

I found the same issue with various other directories:

```
/Library/Caches/Homebrew
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/etc
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/local/opt
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/share/man
/usr/local
```

When I installed RVM, I did a single user install into a non admin account. This non admin account I will be using as my development account. Is this ok, or should I be developing using an admin account? I am running into all sorts of permissions type issues; eg trying to install a gem, because of write permissions failures and am now questioning what is the proper way to develop code, without being an admin, or should I be an admin?

I was going to start using chown to fix these errors ie

> chown $USER -R /usr/local/bin

but, this worries me. Do I want to be changing the owner of all these system directories to my non admin account? Just want some re-assurance  really before I go ahead, it just feels, wrong. (PS; is that the correct use of chown?)

I've seen other articles that suggest using sudo, but I've also seen artciles that say you shouldn't use sudo. Err-ing on the side of caution, I would rather not use sudo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these questions are pretty well covered by the [Homebrew FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-insist-i-install-to-usrlocal-with-such-vehemence).

> Do I want to be changing the owner of all these system directories to my non admin account?

System libraries are not installed to `/usr/local`. Apple doesn't include that directory on a clean install. Most likely some other installer put things there as root or another user.

> I've seen other articles that suggest using sudo, but I've also seen artciles that say you shouldn't use sudo.

Homebrew should *not* be used with `sudo`, but it does assume the user is an admin and has rights to `/usr/local`. If you are just referring to fixing the permissions with `chown`, that will require `sudo` (and admin account).

Comment: Ok thanks Ian. I shall take a deeper look into homebrew. In the end, I did chown all those folders (needed sudo for that); but I cant remember if I installed homebrew with sudo or not! I have taken to recording all output from all commands because I'm starting to lose track of what I've done. Everything's working ok at the moment, I just need to do a significant amount of reading which is no problem, but it is a problem when those references are out of date which happens too regularly. Oh and having to develop as an admin, I thought that was not recommended, but I guess I'll need to change tht